# chkconfig not starting application script on bootup

Tags: linux, centos, boot, service, chkconfig

OS: Centos 5.7

My application script starts like this (/etc/init.d/myapp):

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig 2345 85 60
# description: my application controller
# processname: myapp

NAME=MyApp
DIR=/opt/myapp/
RUN_AS=root

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myapp
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       Starts the myapp application
### END INIT INFO
```

Chkconfig status

```
chkconfig --list | grep myapp

myapp            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

myapp accepts start | stop | restart | force-reload and they're all tested to work

myapp controller basically needs to start some daemon services for the application. If I run `service myapp start` after the system is rebooted, everything works fine. But for some reason, chkconfig is not starting it up automatically. Can anyone explain what I may be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to cjc's information, it appears that my application controller is loading prior to some required services such as mysql.

Here's the result of a quick search:

```
find /etc -name rc* -type d | xargs ls | grep myapp
K50myapp
K50myapp
S50myapp
S50myapp
S50myapp
S50myapp
K50myapp
```

So why is the order set to 50 when in the script I've set to 85(start) 60(stop)? And how can I change this?

**Solution** (as pointed out by cjc in comments to his answer)

Incorrect syntax:

```
# chkconfig 2345 85 60
```

Correct to (colon needed after chkconfig):

```
# chkconfig: 2345 85 60
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

chkconfig essentially makes a symlink from, say, /etc/rc3.d/S85myapp to /etc/init.d/myapp.  Verify that those links exist.  I assume they do, since the "chkconfig --list" is showing that they're "on".

Since you can execute /etc/init.d/myapp from prompt, but it doesn't occur during startup, my guess is that there's an issue with the PATH, or that a service that you need up and running before executing myapp is actually initializing after myapp.  Remember that the scripts in /etc/rc3.d (or whatever your initial runlevel is) are executed in sort order.  Verify that myapp has everything it needs to run.

(My guess it that there's a PATH issue, though)

Comment: They're current showing up in `/etc/rcx.d/S50myapp`, and you're right, some services that are required load up after this. Like mysql is `S62mysql`. How can I change this sort order?

Comment: Check the man page for chkconfig, the "RUNLEVEL FILES" section. Basically, the "# chkconfig 2345 85 60" line in your file. From that, it should be S85, which would start it after mysql. I guess you may have created the links prior to changing that line.  In this case, I'd do "chkconfig --del myapp" to remove the links, and then "chkconfig --add myapp" to add them again. In the worst case, you can rename the symlinks in the /etc/rc?.d directories.

Comment: `chkconfig --del myapp` does delete all the symlinks. But `chkconfig --add myapp` again sets them S60myapp. If I rename them manually, it might be an issue in the future if someone else decides to make changes to the script. I can't understand why it's being set to 50 when I'm clearly setting it to 85 60.

Comment: Looking at my /etc/init.d, I see the line is actually "# chkconfig:   2345 85 60".  Check your syntax; don't miss the colon after chkconfig.

Comment: That was it! Thanks cjc. Appreciate your patience with this!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the $PATH -- it lead me to check my init file, and it seems it was using a pid.lock file but not actually checking that the process was up, which caused a stale lock file preventing the daemon from starting. Thought it might help others if I mention this scenario.